# Query to Find company name where salary than 4000

Tags: sql

I have three tables `company`, `employee` and `salary` and I want to a query to print the names of every company where the average salary is greater than or equal to 4000 grouped by company.name

Salary table has `empployee_id, company_id and salary`

I tried this but I am not sure this is right. I am new to sql.

```
select COMPANY.NAME, avg(SALARY.SALARY)
from COMPANY C join
     SALARY S
     on C.ID = S.ID 
group by C.NAME
having avg(S.SALARY) >= 4000
```

Comment: does all the company have id in salary table

Comment: The query looks file, are you sure  in C.ID = S.ID , S.ID point the company_id column in salary table

Comment: Just FYI, since you mentioned being new to sql. You should reference the alias in your select as a good practice. So instead of `COMPANY.NAME` it should be `C.NAME`.

Comment: @psaraj12 yes....

Comment: why would company have an id in the salary table? salary should be tied to employee, and employee to company. Can you provide more details on your schema?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is your `s.id` that is getting you. In essence you are inner joining on `salary.Id = company.Id` and those two should never match, you want to do it on `salary.company_id = company.id`

```
SELECT c.[name], AVG(s.salary)
FROM company AS c 
INNER JOIN salary AS s ON s.company_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.[name]
HAVING AVG(s.salary) >= 4000
```

Comment: No need to use emp.id any where in query?

Comment: @kittu you arent using an employee for anything. Did you want to list the employees who had the average survey?

Comment: @gh9 . . . You have a lot of reputation.  I'm surprised you can't do a better job formatting the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I formated the way I like to read it and the way my co-workes like to read it. Your style isn't as readable. It is an opionion argument so lets just drop it

Comment: @gh9 . . . I was referring to the use of single back ticks in the answer for multiple lines of code.  That is Stack Overflow and has nothing to do with your coworkers.